# Hover or click on dropdown menu

Tags: dropdown, drop-down-list, hover

My application allows a PNG export thanks to my 'E' button. The user can choose to export the image with captions or without it.

The client with which I am working doesn't like the hover effect on my 'E' button. 
Is there a way to improve the way I am hovering my button, or do I have to add a click event in order to drop down the menu? 
I think it is useless and not  intuitive to add a click (because of the not-meaning of the 'E') but I'm not really sure.

[image] and when it's hovered :     [image]

Comment: What exactly is the clients issue with the hover? What did they say? And why exactly do you dislike clicks? Hovering over something in order to trigger a menu isn't really the most user-friendly method anyway as it requires precise positioning *and* maintaining that position within a small area of the screen. A click to open the menu requires far less precision to use the menu item itself anyway, so I'm tempted to agree with your client, but you'll need to explain the actual problem you have and why you don't like the solution in a bit more detail if we're to be able to help you here.

Comment: My client doesn't like the way to point on something which can disappear if the mouse is too much on the right or on the left. I don't like the click event on this button because 'E'doesn't mean something, the user doesn't know if it's a button or I don't know some decoration. With the hover he can directly knows this 'E' is hidding inside its an action.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty sensible complain from your client, to be fair. And seems to support what I alluded to in my comment. So the next question is - what is your problem with changing it to a click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest Click instead of hover, there are few reasons:

1. Mobile/Tablets do not have hover state
2. Hover creates tunnels that require greater mouse precision
3. Accidental hover over/out

Check out this article on [uxmovement](http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-hover-menus-do-users-more-harm-than-good/)